# Can "spin on" mean "keep spinning"?

Tags: phrases, phrasal-verbs, alternatives

Can "on" indicate repetition on itself? For instance, does the sentence *the planet spins on* express the same thing as *the planet keeps spinning*?

Comment: It can do, but some context is needed. Another example is "You want to win the tango competition? Dance on!"

Comment: And in context, it might mean something completely different, e.g., "He hired a publicist to put a different *spin on* his statement." Here, it means to make a condition *appear* to be different, as in *The Emperor's New Clothes*.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik My question was whether "spin on" *can* mean repetition, specifically in the sentence "The planet spins on."

Comment: @WeatherVane The context is the sentence "The planet spins on." Does it make sense in its own?

Comment: As I [wrote](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/241501/can-spin-on-mean-keep-spinning?noredirect=1#comment456493_241501), there is more context needed. The sentence "the planets spins on" doesn't make much sense on its own, and you have not got agreeing plural/conjugation. It should be either "the planets spin on" or "the planet spins on." But the preposition "on" can be used like that: "carry on".

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks, so I need *on and on* to indicate repetition